# Finding the size of a screen pixel in UV coordinates for use by the fragment shader

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, shader, fragment-shader

I've got a very detailed texture (with false color information I'm rendering with a false-color lookup in the fragment shader).  My problem is that sometimes the user will zoom far away from this texture, and the fine detail will be lost: fine lines in the texture can't be seen. I would like to modify my code to make these lines pop out.

My thinking is that I can run fast filter over neighboring textels and pick out the biggest/smallest/most interesting value to render.  What I'm not sure how to do is to find out if (and how much) to do this. When the user is zoomed into a triangle, I want the standard lookup. When they are zoomed out, a single pixel on the screen maps to many texture pixels.

How do I get an estimate of this? I am doing this with both orthogographic and perspective cameras.

My thinking is that I could somehow use the vertex shader to get an estimate of how big one screen pixel is in UV space and pass that as a varying to the fragment shader, but I still don't have a solid grasp on either the transforms and spaces enough to get the idea.

My current vertex shader is quite simple:

```
  varying vec2 vUv;
  varying vec3 vPosition;
  varying vec3 vNormal;
  varying vec3 vViewDirection;

   void main() {
       vUv = uv;
       vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
       vPosition = (modelMatrix *
           vec4(position,1.0)).xyz;
       gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
      vec3 transformedNormal = normalMatrix *  vec3( normal );
      vNormal = normalize( transformedNormal );
      vViewDirection = normalize(mvPosition.xyz);
   }
```

How do I get something like vDeltaUV, which gives the distance between screen pixels in UV units?

Constraints: I'm working in WebGL, inside three.js.

Here is an example of one image, where the user has zoomed perspective in close to my texture:
[image: Here is an image zoomed in]

Here is the same example, but zoomed out; the feature above is a barely-perceptible diagonal line near the center (see the coordinates to get a sense of scale).  I want this line to pop out by rendering all pixels with the red-est color of the corresponding array of textels.

[image: Here is the image zoomed out]

Addendum (re LJ's comment)...
No, I don't think mipmapping will do what I want here, for two reasons.

First, I'm not actually mapping the texture; that is, I'm doing something like this:

```
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(mappingtexture,  texture2d(vec2(inputtexture.g,inputtexture.r))
```

The user dynamically creates the mappingtexture, which allows me to vary the false-color map in realtime.  I think it's actually a very elegant solution to my application.

Second, I don't want to draw the AVERAGE value of neighboring pixels (i.e. smoothing) I want the most EXTREME value of neighboring pixels (i.e. something more akin to edge finding).  "Extreme" in this case is technically defined by my encoding of the g/r color values in the input texture.

Solution:
Thanks to the answer below, I've now got a working solution.

In my javascript code, I had to add:

```
  extensions: {derivatives: true}
```

to my declaration of the ShaderMaterial.  Then in my fragment shader:

```
   float dUdx = dFdx(vUv.x); // Difference in U between this pixel and the one to the right.
  float dUdy = dFdy(vUv.x); // Difference in U between this pixel and the one to the above.
  float dU = sqrt(dUdx*dUdx + dUdy*dUdy);
  float pixel_ratio = (dU*(uInputTextureResolution));
```

This allows me to do things like this:

```
   float x = ... the u coordinate in pixels in the input texture
   float y = ... the v coordinate in pixels in the input texture
   vec4 inc = get_encoded_adc_value(x,y);

   // Extremum mapping:
   if(pixel_ratio>2.0) {
    inc = most_extreme_value(inc, get_encoded_adc_value(x+1.0, y));
   }
   if(pixel_ratio>3.0) {
    inc = most_extreme_value(inc, get_encoded_adc_value(x-1.0, y));    
  }
```

The effect is subtle, but definitely there! The lines pop much more clearly.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this in the vertex shader as it's pre-rasterization stage hence output resolution agnostic, but in the fragment shader you could use [dFdx, dFdy](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/dFdx.xhtml) [and fwidth](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/fwidth.xhtml) using the `GL_OES_standard_derivatives` extension(which is available pretty much everywhere) to estimate the sampling footprint.

If you're not updating the texture in realtime a simpler and more efficient solution would be to generate custom mip levels for it on the CPU.

Comment: That looks interesting. I'll look to see if there are any tutorials on these functions.
The textures are indeed dynamically generated, so that's time-consuming in a real-time app. Even if I DID have them, i would still need a reliable way of choosing which texture to use.

Comment: The GPU already does this for you, that's what mip mapping is all about, selecting the mip level closest to a 1 to 1 texel/screen-pixel ratio. Using your approach(as in, not using the suggested method of generating custom mip maps) is only faster if your texture is generated every frame and your zoom levels are rather small(like a 2-4 minification), in every other case mipmaps will be a lot faster and if the CPU were to become a bottleneck you could move that load to the GPU too.

Comment: @LJ I don't think so; addendum above